# ASM Bytecode Method Parameter Values

Tags: java-bytecode-asm

How to view or access the method parameter values or Objects using ASM Byte Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account method parameter types, you could do something like that:

```
int off = (access | Opcodes.ACC_STATIC) == 0 ? 0 : 1;
int opcode = Type.getArgumentTypes(desc)[param + off].getOpcode(Opcodes.IALOAD);
mv.visitVarIns(opcode, param);
...
```

where `param` is method parameter number and `access` and `desc` are values you get from corresponding parameters of [ClassVisitor.html#visitMethod](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor.html#visitMethod%28int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).

Comment: shouldn't `access | Opcodes.ACC_STATIC`  be `access & Opcodes.ACC_STATIC` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Method arguments are the first few local variables.  To access the first arg, the bytecode mnemonic looks like `aload_0` or `iload_0` or `lload_0` etc, depending on the argument's type.  For arguments past the fourth, you'd say `aload 4` etc.

Note, the first argument to an instance method is a reference to `this`.  So the first argument will be local #1, and you'd get it like `aload_1` etc.

However you'd generate bytecode with the ASM stuff... do that.  It looks like you'd say something akin to `mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);`, where `mv` is your MethodVisitor.  The `0` would be replaced with the local variable index.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply.. Can u give some examples using ASM?

Comment: Not really; i've never used the stuff, and find it hard to even understand *why* it works, much less *how*, partly due to the rampant visitor abuse.  Looks like *everything* is a Visitor of some kind.  :P  A real bytecode generation library would be more straightforward; see .net's `System.Reflection.Emit`.